# Which is best architecture to be followed in iOS application development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mvvm, mvp

Previously we were using MVC architecture to design iOS apps. But as today we mostly work on TDD (Test Driven Development), we use different architectures. So I am little confused which architecture we can use. 
I made one sample using MVP and one in MVVM (Github link: https://github.com/pushkrajlanjekar/MVVM-Demo)

But when I read some blogs some people are with MVP and some are with MVVM. So can some one suggest me, which is the best architecture to be followed? If possible share some reference links.

Answer (score 4):

Software architecture depends on the technology, methodology and project requirements that are set.
It is quite hard to highlight where to use or where not to use certain architecture solutions. It is possible only to share own opinion.

From my point of view one of the most interested and modern architecture for the iOS development is [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/). Because it create certain business layers with **SOLID** software principles and clear architecture of the application. Also based on latest Swift changes it is possibly to conclude that implementation of the project on protocol oriented programing and VIPER is quite easy.

Main resources:

[Architecting iOS Apps with VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/)

[Video presentation](https://realm.io/news/altconf-brice-pollock-250-days-shipping-with-swift-and-viper/)

[Clean Swift iOS Architecture for Fixing Massive View Controller](http://clean-swift.com/clean-swift-ios-architecture/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
https://github.com/devxoul/RxTodo
this is the best example i found so far regarding MVVM + RxSwift(which i strongly suggest).
The difference between MVVM and MVP is mostly data bindings. Personally i prefer using MVVM and RxSwift for databindings. It makes code much more clean and lousily coupled.
If you want to avoid data bindings MVP is a better choice.